# Can I use Datastore as SQL database?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql, serverless

On GCP - We are looking for a SQL database but specifically need a serverless option. Also, our requirement is for less amount of data.
Could we use Datastore for same?

Comment: Cloud SQL is also serverless and it supports SQL server. Datastore is NO SQL Database

Answer (score 0):

All depends for doing what! To store data, without transactional consistency, poor querying option, no JDBC support and not relational model; yes you can.

Else, not, it's not SQL database, you can't do more than storing document!

Comment: Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode has both transactions (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions) & strong consistency

Comment: Yes, on a single document. You can't have relation between several document, in different entity, and stored them transactionally. In any case, it's a no sense because you won't have contraint violation.

Comment: From the linked doc "You can create, update, or delete up to 500 entities in each transaction. The maximum size of a transaction is 10 MiB."

Comment: Hmmm, correct, my mistake came from the lock, not performed on the database, but only locally. But yes, there are transactions, but not really the same implementation as in SQL engine!

Answer (score 0):

As Guillaume and Prany said, Datastore is a No SQL database, so, if you want to use a SQL one, [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore) is not the option.

On the other hand, you can choose between the following options:

- [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql) that provides a cloud-based alternative to local MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server databases. You should use Cloud SQL if you want to spend less time managing your database and more time using it.

-[Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs) that  is Google Cloud’s massively scalable relational database service. A core tenet of Spanner’s vision has been ensuring high availability of applications with external strong consistency.

So, both are SQL databases, both are serverless but the difference between them is that Cloud SQL is the horizontal scalability + globally available of data over 10TB that Cloud Spanner offers.

Spanner is not for CRM database, it is more for supermassive global data within an organisation and since spanner is bit expensive (compared to cloud SQL) the project should be large enough to justify the cost of spanner.

Comment: Now pricing of cloud spanner starts @ $65